# Abu Dhabi to Muscat?

Tags: buses, uae, oman, abu-dhabi

I will be traveling from Abu Dhabi to Muscat in February this year but I can't find any conclusive information as to whether direct connections (that are not flights) between the two cities exist and what the details are.

[ONTC](http://www.ontcoman.com/) appears to operate a bus service between Dubai and Muscat and though some online sources claim they also travel between Abu Dhabi and Muscat, their website does not suggest this.

Who has the lowdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. That was fairly painless.

ONTC does not provide a service between Abu Dhabi and Muscat. From Dubai to Muscat, buses leave at 7:30, 15:30 and 23:00, arriving at, respectively, 13:40, 21:35 and 5:00 (the next day).

The price is quoted at 5.500, which probably means 5.5, which is about 11 euros, one way.

I got this from the horse's mouth, ONTC responded to my email query within 15 minutes.

They tell me the bus departs from the ONTC office, which is in Dubai Dunta car park (0097104042525909), though I can't find that on Google Maps.

Comment: Excellent idea to contact them by email!

Comment: :) Well. I really didn't expect them to respond, let alone so quickly. But it might also not be the only connection between UAE en Oman.

Comment: I would rent a car and drive, its a lovely drive I have done it with friends back in 1999.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's indeed an alternative I'm considering. Rent is cheap, less than 20 euros per day.

Comment: That's indeed an excellent suggestion!

Comment: But... renting from Dubai does require you to purchase an Omani insurance, which costs 60 euros for 7 days for a small car. That's more than 50% of the rental price. :(

Comment: I ended up renting a car, so I never went to the bus station.