# Travelling to Oman by Bus from Dubai

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, dubai, uae, oman

I am a British National, I am entitled to Visa on arrival at Dubai Airport up to 30 days.

1. Can I travel to Oman by road? (either car or bus) whilst on visit to UAE, Oman govt also allows a British national visa on arrival for a fee of 6 OMR.
2. Is this facility available at the border ?

I will be in Oman only for two days.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/abu-dhabi-to-muscat

Answer (score 2):

You can see at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/abu-dhabi-to-muscat) that you can take a bus from Dubai to Muscat. You can also rent a car.

I made this trip three years ago, as a Dutch national, and don't remember having any issue obtaining a tourist visa at the border.